# Как реализовать демо-вычисления

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css3

Я написал скрипт и форму, по которой производятся и считаются вычисления при нажатии на кнопку "Вычислить". Помогите пожалуйста, как можно реализовать демо-вычисления: при нажатии на кнопку "Демо", значения по умолчанию вставляются в соответствующие им поля, но до нажатия на на кнопку "Демо", поля должны быть пустыми.

```js
 function proverka(input) {
   var value = input.value;
   var rep = /[-;":'a-zA-Zа-яА-Я\\=`ё/\*++!@#$%\^&_№?><]/;
   if (rep.test(value)) {
     value = value.replace(rep, '');
     input.value = value;
   }
 }

 function areaRectangle() {
   this.calc1();
   var H1 = +document.forma1.t1.value || 0;
   var H2 = +document.forma1.t2.value || 0;
   var l1 = H2 - H1;
   document.forma1.t3[0].value = H1;
   document.forma1.t3[1].value = H2;
   document.forma1.t3[2].value = l1;

   if ((H1 == 0) || (H2 == 0) || (p1 == 0) || (p2 == 0)) { //сообщаем пользователю в диалоговом окне, о том что при нажатии на кнопку вычислить, 
     alert('Входные данные не могут быть равны 0'); //входные данные "ограничены", поэтому если пользователь
     return; //введет их неправильно, то ему придётся ввести данные ещё раз, но на этот раз правильно
   }
   if ((H1 < 0) || (H2 < 0) || (p1 < 0) || (p2 < 0)) {
     alert('Входные данные не могут быть меньше 0');
     return;
   }
   if (H2 < H1) {
     alert('H2 должно быть больше H1');
     return;
   }

   var p1 = document.forma1.t4.value;
   var p2 = document.forma1.t5.value;
   var L = H2 - l1 * (p1 / p2 || 0);
   document.forma1.res.value = L;
 }

 function calc1() { //в подрасчёте есть промежуточное значение l1
   console.log(1); //пользователь узнает чему равно l1, только после ввода H1 и H2, и нажатия на
   var H1 = +document.forma1.t1.value || 0; //текстовое поле t3
   var H2 = +document.forma1.t2.value || 0;
   var l1 = H2 - H1;
   document.forma1.t3[0].value = H1;
   document.forma1.t3[1].value = H2;
   document.forma1.t3[2].value = l1;
 }

 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
   document.forma1.t1.addEventListener("keyup", calc1);
   document.forma1.t2.addEventListener("keyup", calc1);
 });
```

```html
<form name="forma1" style="background-color:#44944A;">
  <!-- поменяю цвет формы -->
  <div id="resizable">
    <!--"подрасчёт 1.1"-->
    <table align="center">
      <br>
      <p align="center">Глубина установки конца заливочных труб</p>
      <tr>
        <td height="40px">
          <div class="price" title="H1">Расстояние от устья скважины до нижних отверстий фильтра, м;</div>
          <input name="t1" type="text" align="right" size="4" maxlength="8" onkeyup="return proverka(this)" id="t3">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="40px">
          <div class="price" title="H2">Расстояние от устья скважины до верхних отверстий фильтра, м;</div>
          <input name="t2" type="text" align="right" size="4" maxlength="8" onkeyup="return proverka(this)" id="t3">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="40px">
          <div class="price">Интервал отверстий фильтра, м;</div>
          <input name="t3" type="text" align="right" size="4" maxlength="8" onkeyup="return proverka(this)" id="t3">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="40px">
          <div class="price">Плотность цементного раствора, кг/м<sup>3</sup>;</div>
          <input name="t4" type="text" align="right" size="4" maxlength="8" onkeyup="return proverka(this)">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="40px">
          <div class="price">Плотность жидкости, находящейся в скважине, кг/м<sup>3</sup>;</div>
          <input name="t5" type="text" align="right" size="4" maxlength="8" onkeyup="return proverka(this)">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="button" name="button" value="Вычислить" onClick="areaRectangle();">
          <input type="text" name="res" size="10">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <br>
</form>
```

Функция calc1 нужна для вычисления промежуточного значения l1

Под формулой есть значения по умолчанию для демо-вычислений
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как вариант инпутам добавляете атрибут data со значениями для демо вичислений. При нажатии на кнопку демо прописываете эти значения в инпуты и запускаете функцию вычисления.

Comment: Есть вариант попроще, но я не думаю что получится с двумя id:                                
один раз id задаются для вычисления промежуточного значения, а второй раз нужно для demo

Comment: "При нажатии на кнопку демо прописываете эти значения в инпуты" а как это сделать?

Comment: Добавил ответ. В javascript не очень силен поетому реализовал добавление с помощью jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если через jqery то как то так:

```js
 function proverka(input) {
   var value = input.value;
   var rep = /[-;":'a-zA-Zа-яА-Я\\=`ё/\*++!@#$%\^&_№?><]/;
   if (rep.test(value)) {
     value = value.replace(rep, '');
     input.value = value;
   }
 }

 function areaRectangle() {
   this.calc1();
   var H1 = +document.forma1.t1.value || 0;
   var H2 = +document.forma1.t2.value || 0;
   var l1 = H2 - H1;
   document.forma1.t3[0].value = H1;
   document.forma1.t3[1].value = H2;
   document.forma1.t3[2].value = l1;

   if ((H1 == 0) || (H2 == 0) || (p1 == 0) || (p2 == 0)) { //сообщаем пользователю в диалоговом окне, о том что при нажатии на кнопку вычислить, 
     alert('Входные данные не могут быть равны 0'); //входные данные "ограничены", поэтому если пользователь
     return; //введет их неправильно, то ему придётся ввести данные ещё раз, но на этот раз правильно
   }
   if ((H1 < 0) || (H2 < 0) || (p1 < 0) || (p2 < 0)) {
     alert('Входные данные не могут быть меньше 0');
     return;
   }
   if (H2 < H1) {
     alert('H2 должно быть больше H1');
     return;
   }

   var p1 = document.forma1.t4.value;
   var p2 = document.forma1.t5.value;
   var L = H2 - l1 * (p1 / p2 || 0);
   document.forma1.res.value = L;
 }

 function calc1() { //в подрасчёте есть промежуточное значение l1
   console.log(1); //пользователь узнает чему равно l1, только после ввода H1 и H2, и нажатия на
   var H1 = +document.forma1.t1.value || 0; //текстовое поле t3
   var H2 = +document.forma1.t2.value || 0;
   var l1 = H2 - H1;
   document.forma1.t3[0].value = H1;
   document.forma1.t3[1].value = H2;
   document.forma1.t3[2].value = l1;
 }

 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
   document.forma1.t1.addEventListener("keyup", calc1);
   document.forma1.t2.addEventListener("keyup", calc1);
 });


/* демо вычисления */
$(function(){
  $("#demo").click(function(){
  var H1 = $(".h1").attr("data");
  var H2 = $(".h2").attr("data");
  var L1 = H2-H1;
  var Pup = $("#pup").attr("data");
  var Pzh = $("#pzh").attr("data");
  var L = H2-L1*(Pup/Pzh);
  
  $(".h1").val(H1);
  $(".h2").val(H2);
  $(".l1").val(L1);
  $("#pup").val(Pup);
  $("#pzh").val(Pzh);
  $("#l").val(L);  
    
  });
  
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="forma1" style="background-color:#44944A;">
  <!-- поменяю цвет формы -->
  <div id="resizable">
    <!--"подрасчёт 1.1"-->
    <table align="center">
      <br>
      <p align="center">Глубина установки конца заливочных труб</p>
      <tr>
        <td height="40px">
          <div class="price" title="H1">Расстояние от устья скважины до нижних отверстий фильтра, м;</div>
          <input name="t1" type="text" align="right" size="4" maxlength="8" onkeyup="return proverka(this)" id="t3" class="h1" data="4550">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="40px">
          <div class="price" title="H2">Расстояние от устья скважины до верхних отверстий фильтра, м;</div>
          <input name="t2" type="text" align="right" size="4" maxlength="8" onkeyup="return proverka(this)" id="t3" class="h2" data="4566">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="40px">
          <div class="price">Интервал отверстий фильтра, м;</div>
          <input name="t3" type="text" align="right" size="4" maxlength="8" onkeyup="return proverka(this)" id="t3" class="l1">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="40px">
          <div class="price">Плотность цементного раствора, кг/м<sup>3</sup>;</div>
          <input name="t4" type="text" align="right" size="4" maxlength="8" onkeyup="return proverka(this)" id="pup"  data="1800">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="40px">
          <div class="price">Плотность жидкости, находящейся в скважине, кг/м<sup>3</sup>;</div>
          <input name="t5" type="text" align="right" size="4" maxlength="8" onkeyup="return proverka(this)" id="pzh" data="1080">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="button" name="button" value="Вычислить" onClick="areaRectangle();">
          <input type="button" name="button" value="Вычислить Демо" id="demo">
          <input type="text" name="res" size="10" id="l">
          
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <br>
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо, на вашем сайте работает, но на моём denwer-е ничего не происходит при нажатии на кнопку "Вычислить Демо", будто бы он игнорирует её (код я не менял, только ваш вставил).

Comment: я добавил функцию в скрипт, в хтмл подключил jqery и добавил некоторые стили к инпутам. Проверьте или подключен jqery: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>. Если Вы полностю скопировали все в свой проект то оно должно работать.

Comment: Спасибо, исправил, но теперь он счиатет немного по другому, он будто бы считает не 4550-..., а 4566-...
Ладно, не суть, но скорее всего в учебнике была опечатка

Comment: Там в учебнеке однозначно ошыбка. На картинке посмотрите в формуле где методика расчета написано Н2, а в формуле где происходит сам расчет стоит значение Н1. Уточните етот момент у того кто дал Вам задание

Comment: Есть вопрос, как в этом скрипте округлить например до сотых результат L

$(function(){
  $("#demo").click(function(){
  var H1 = $(".h1").attr("data");
  var H2 = $(".h2").attr("data");
  var L1 = H2-H1;
  var Pup = $("#pup").attr("data");
  var Pzh = $("#pzh").attr("data");
  var L = H2-L1*(Pup/Pzh);
  
  $(".h1").val(H1);
  $(".h2").val(H2);
  $(".l1").val(L1);
  $("#pup").val(Pup);
  $("#pzh").val(Pzh);
  $("#l").val(L);  
    
  }); 
  });